# Sass math function with interpolation

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to pass the interpolation variable inside sass math round to get a round-off value output.

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .col-print-#{$i}{
        width: #{$i * 8.33} + "%";
        float: left;
    }
}
```

The above code is working, but I am getting width in decimals. Note that I am using this already in my file: `@use 'sass:math'`.

I am trying to make a round off value for the width instead of decimals:

```
.col-print-11 {
  width: 91.63%;
  float: left;
}
```

Instead of the above code, I want the width to be rounded off to the nearest:

```
.col-print-11 {
  width: 92%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`math.round`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#round) from the `sass:math` module to round the calculated value to the nearest whole number, like so:

```scss
@use "sass:math";

@for $i from 1 through 12 {
  .col-print-#{$i} {
    width: #{math.round($i * 8.33)} + "%";
    float: left;
  }
}
```